# ApexMock FileNotFound Exception

Tags: apex, mock, apexmock

I am trying to learn how to write tests for apex services using ApexMocks framework. I want to generate Mock classes through apex-mocks-generator and I am following simple instructions given in [this article.](https://code4cloud.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/new-improved-apex-mocks-generator/)

I download repository from GitHub and placed required apex files to src/classes location. I run following in from my terminal:

> java -jar apex-mocks-generator-3.0.1.jar src/classes IAccountUpdate mockAccountUpdate src/results

Error:

> sourcePath=src/classes
>   interfaces=IAccountUpdate
>   mocksClassname=mockAccountUpdate
>   targetPath=src/results
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   IAccountUpdate (The system cannot find the file specified)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.financialforce.apexmocks.MocksGenerator.(MocksGenerator.jav
>   a:34)
>           at com.financialforce.apexmocks.ApexMockGenerator.main(ApexMockGenerator
>   .java:31)

I have tried the [older version of this generator which has a different command to create mocks](https://code4cloud.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/using-apex-mocks-generator-to-create-mock-class-definitions/). And it also gives `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. Interface is present in src folder. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, are you also using a relative path (from the `.jar`)? The examples seem to indicate that you can do this, but I'm curious if that is causing it to not be found

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using the new [`4.0.1.jar`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks/blob/master/apex-mocks-generator-4.0.1.jar). I placed the .jar script along with the [`interfacemocks.properties`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks/blob/master/interfacemocks.properties) file in my environment folder just before the `/src/` directory. Then from my terminal (I use [Cmder](http://cmder.net/)), from the directory of the .jar I ran the following

```
java -jar apex-mocks-generator-4.0.1.jar "src\classes" "interfacemocks.properties" "Mocks" "src\classes"
```

This then populated my `Mocks.cls` (already created previous to running the command) with the mock interfaces I defined in the `interfacemocks.properties` file.

**NOTE:** Notice the relative paths did not include a preceding `\` as [the documentation suggest](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks#generating-mock-files). Also a previous tutorial showed an example without the `""` wrappers for each parameter, but I found I needed those like the ApexMocks documentation/readme indicates